# Show elements matching multiple selected data attributes

Tags: jquery, filtering, custom-data-attribute

I am creating a set of filters and once they are selected, corresponding divs should show based on ALL of the attributes being selected.

I can get this to work one at a time, but my issue is when trying to get them to work together.  I feel like there is probably a better approach to this in general?

Here are my select menus:

```
<div class="filters">
 <select class="filter-location">
   <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Location</option>
   <option data-location="Remote">Remote – United States</option>
   <option data-location="Portland, OR">Portland, OR</option>
   <option data-location="Seattle, WA">Seattle, WA</option>
 </select>
 <select class="filter-team">
   <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Team</option>
   <option data-team="Sales">Sales</option>
   <option data-team="Support">Support</option>
   <option data-team="Management">Management</option>
 </select>
 <select class="filter-type">
   <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Type</option>
   <option data-type="Full-Time">Full-Time</option>
   <option data-type="Contract">Contract</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Here is a simplified version of my HTML markup:

```
<div class="job" data-team="Sales" data-location="Remote" data-type="Full-Time">
  <p>Job Content Here</p>
</div>
<div class="job" data-team="Management" data-location="Portland, OR" data-type="Contract">
  <p>Job Content Here</p>
</div>
<div class="job" data-team="Sales" data-location="Seattle, WA" data-type="Full-Time">
  <p>Job Content Here</p>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery that works for showing one filter at a time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.filters select').on('change', function() {

      var location_value = $(':selected', this).data('location');
      var team_value = $(':selected', this).data('team');
      var type_value = $(':selected', this).data('type');

      $('.job').hide();

      $(".job").each(function( index ) {
        if ($(this).data('location') == location_value) {
          $(this).show();
        }
        if ($(this).data('team') == team_value) {
          $(this).show();
        }
        if ($(this).data('work_type') == type_value) {
          $(this).show();
        }
      });

    });
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Your main issue is you need `&&` logic to make sure each condition matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following creates an array of filter objects for each `<select>` that has a value that looks like:

```
[
  {
    "filter": "location",
    "value": "Remote"
  },
  {
    "filter": "team",
    "value": "Sales"
  }
]
```

It then uses [Array#every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to make sure that each filter matches a job's `data-` attributes to determine whether to show it or not.

Note I made the `<select>` elements  a bit more generic and added a `data-filter` attribute to each one and just used `value` on the `<option>` elements

```js
const $sels = $('.filters select'),
      $jobs = $('.job')

$sels.change(function(){
    const filters = $sels.filter(function(){
        return !!this.value
    }).map(function(){
       return {filter: $(this).data('filter'), value : this.value} 
    }).get();
    //console.log('Filters', filters)    
    
    // hide all jobs then filter the ones to show
    const $filterJobs = $jobs.hide().filter(function(){
        const data = $(this).data()
        return filters.every(function(obj){
           return data[obj.filter] === obj.value 
        });
    }).show(); 

    // toggle "no-match" depending on length of filter jobs collection
    $('#no-match').toggle( !$filterJobs.length )

});
```

```css
.job, #no-match {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  <select data-filter="location">
    <option value="">Location</option>
    <option value="Remote">Remote – United States</option>
    <option value="Portland, OR">Portland, OR</option>
    <option value="Seattle, WA">Seattle, WA</option>
  </select>
  <select data-filter="team">
    <option value="">Team</option>
    <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
    <option value="Support">Support</option>
    <option value="Management">Management</option>
  </select>
  <select data-filter="type">
    <option value="">Type</option>
    <option value="Full-Time">Full-Time</option>
    <option value="Contract">Contract</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="no-match">
   <h3>No Match</h3>
</div>

<div class="job" data-team="Sales" data-location="Remote" data-type="Full-Time">
  <p>Sales Remote Full Time</p>
</div>
<div class="job" data-team="Management" data-location="Portland, OR" data-type="Contract">
  <p>Management Portland Contract</p>
</div>
<div class="job" data-team="Sales" data-location="Seattle, WA" data-type="Full-Time">
  <p>Sales Seattle Full Time</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew something was missing.  This works perfectly.